# Why my service can't be destroyed

Tags: android, service

Sorry for my English.

I have one Activity that call one service and i want to stop this service from that Activity.

I try to use stopService(getApplicationContext(), TempService.class) And it doesn't worked.

Here is my service code

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("Debug", "Service start");
    mgr = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE); 

    temp = mgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);

    mgr.registerListener(this, temp, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);



    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

public void onDestroy() {
Log.d("DEBUG", "on destroy");
notificationManager.cancel(0);
super.onDestroy();  
}
```

And in my Activity : boolean t always return false value.
I have no idea.

```
private void processStopService(final String tag) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TempService.class);
    intent.addCategory(tag);
    boolean t = stopService(intent);
    if (t)
    {
        Log.e("DEBUG", "TRUE");
    }
    else
        Log.e("DEBUG", "FALSE");
}
```

Comment: you can call stopSelf() within the service

Comment: Maybe it's the "intent.addCategory(tag);" that prevents the intent to resolve to your service. Try removing this line and see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, Now the boolean can return true value. But onDestroy method won't be run Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use categories with services. Delete the `addCategory()` call on your `Intent`.

Comment: Now the boolean return true value
But onDestroy won't be run
Any ideas?

Comment: @SobbSpt: If `stopService()` returns `true`, that means it is stopping the service. `false` means that it could not find a matching service. With respect to `onDestroy()`, that should be invoked. Add the `@Override` annotation to it. BTW, here is a sample app demonstrating the flow that you are doing: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Service/FakePlayer